# Es posible automatizar la función "Subtotales"?

Tags: base-de-datos, excel, vba

Tratare de explicarme lo mejor posible aunque adjuntare imágenes para ayudarme a explicarles...

Sucede que estoy trabajando en una base de datos alojada en Excel (versión 2016 con Sistema operativo Windows 8.1) específicamente debo trabajar en 6 columnas (4 con los datos con los que se traba y 2 que muestran los resultados) las cuales contienen la función `=SUBTOTALES(9; RANGO)`.

Ahora bien el problema es que esta base fue exportada y al exportarla los rangos se modificaron provocando que o no abarque todos los datos que debería o que por el contrario se pase de esos rangos.

Mi trabajo es organizar esos rangos pero son mas de 50.000 registros lo que hace que organizar eso manualmente sea un trabajo largo e ineficiente.

He tratado de usar tablas dinámicas y macros para organizar eso y por desgracia no he logrado nada, me gustaría saber que macro, función, o que configuración general o de tablas dinámicas puedo usar para organizar dichos datos.

[image]

Como ven el rango no abarca todo, yo debo hacer que el cuadro encierre todos los datos y aveces se pasa del rango que debe por lo que debo o ampliar el cuadro o reducirlo, hay diferentes rangos pueden ser solo 3 filas o pueden ser 20, y como dije hacerlo manual seria largo e ineficiente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con este código puede arreglar el archivo:

Esta configurado para arreglarlos en la columna "M" si desea arreglar otra columna solo tiene que cambiar este parámetro con la letra de columna respectiva.

```
Sub FixSubTotals()
    Dim i, j, lastRow As Long

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Toma el valor de cuantas filas hay en la tabla

    j = 0 'inicia el contador desde cero
    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1 'itera cada fila desde la ultima del libro hacia la primera fila
        If Range("A" & i).Value <> 1 Then 'evalúa si el valor en la columna A es diferente de 1
            j = j + 1 'Si es diferente va contando cuantas filas hay entre subtotales.
        Else
            Worksheets("APU").Range("M" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUBTOTALES(9,R[1]C[-2]:R[" & j & "]C[-1])" 'Cuando encuentra un 1 asigna la formula subtotal con los rangos que contienen los valores a sumar
            j = 0 'Reinicia el contador para cada rango.
        End If
    Next i 'Pasa a la siguiente fila
End Sub
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Virtualdvid, lo probare y es pero que en caso de tener dudas o problemas pueda preguntarte de nuevo en esta misma pregunta

Comment: Hola amigo, me podrías explicar por favor que que arreglo hace el código ya que lo he implementado en diferentes columnas, pero no he notado un cambio... o tal vez sea que yo no lo introduje o lo estoy usando bien.... 

Lo que hago es abrir el modo desarrollador, luego en la hoja donde aplicare el código hago un modulo, coloco el código y lo ejecuto.

Comment: Exactamente, generalmente guardo los códigos en el libro "Personal" por si los necesito ejecutar en diferentes archivos o por seguridad de que alguien no borre el archivo por accidente. Para llegar a el es fácil, se graba una macro y en el las opciones de donde se quiere grabar se le dice que en libro Personal. Este libro siempre se carga automáticamente cada vez que abrimos Excel.

Comment: Una vez guardado en algún módulo solo es abrir el documento y ejecutar el código. Quisiera saber si le funcionó?

Comment: No he logrado que me funcione, o al menos no veo que haga algún cambio, he cambiado la columna de referencia pero no veo que algo se mueva o modifique, me gustaria saber que es lo que hace el código exactamente

Comment: Ahora me sale un mensaje diciendo:

"Se ha producido el error '6' en tiempo de ejecución:

Desbordamiento"

Comment: Adicione comentarios en cada linea del código. Puede entrar al código y evaluar linea a linea con `F8` y decirme en que linea salta el error?

Comment: Debo depurar para saber donde esta el error?, o como lo veo?

En caso de que deba depurar el error estaria en la linea 3, la que dice "lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row"

Comment: Si, eso lo lleva a la linea que tiene el error.

Comment: Esta en la linea 3, la que dice: "lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row"

Comment: Ya, es porque la variable lastRow en su tabla sobrepasa los limites como `integer` cambie la segunda linea a tipo de dato `Long` ya lo edite en la respuesta. Al finalizar revise el donde están las formulas ya deberían estar corregidas. No es visible el proceso por que el código trabaja internamente para ser mas eficiente y sea mas rápido en ejecución por la cantidad de datos.

Comment: Acutalmente parece que esta trabajando, y haciendo todos, te dejare saber que pasa en cuanto termine

Comment: Amigo, deberían darte un premio, he visitado y preguntado en muchos foros y aunque me han dado buena ayuda nada me había servido como tu código... en verdad te lo agradezco mucho. Espero en algún futuro poder volver a recurrir a ti si tengo problemas con algo

Comment: De nada, acá andamos para ayudar!